# Should I build one or two mongodb models?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean.io

I am building a mean stack app allowing people to read and write reviews about products.

Reviews will be classified by products on the website : A user will open the page displaying the list of products reviewed on the website and see the name of each products. When clicking on a product, the user is directed to a new page displaying all the reviews about the product.

I was set on building just one model gathering all reviews :

```
var ReviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    productName: String,
    productCreator: String,
    review: String,
    upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
    author: String
});
```

The page listing all products would get all reviews from the data base and then only display the productName and productCreator after eliminating all duplicates.

```
<a href="link/to/reviews/aboutProducts">{{productName}} - {{productCreator}}</a>
```

But it's probably not efficient at all. Would it be better to build two different models, one for the reviews and one for the products ?

I'm sorry if my question is stupid but I'm still learning about MEAN and don't know much about non-relational db, that's my first project ;)

Comment: Since mongo is a non-relational database I'm not 100% on this, but I think it is better to have a separate collection for reviews and just link them to the productID. Also, I'm guessing author is a user, you also want that to be a separate collection and be linked together with the uniqID.

Comment: Thanks for your help

I plan on doing a seperate collection for author, I'm just using a String for now to keep things simple.

Anybody else with a 100% answer ? :)

Comment: My $0.02: Create a separate model for each *thing* you have. Here you have "product" and "review" (and probably "author", too). -- As you can see, this question is primarily opinion-based and therefore [not a good fit for StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

I have built two models that I have embedded. It takes a little more time when writing all the rest routes, but it will simplify both the back and front in the end.

Comment: [(Over-)Embedding is the root of all evil](http://blog.mahlberg.io/blog/2015/11/05/data-modelling-for-mongodb/)